Couldn't install almath package
I want to install almath library and I am using Python 3.7 as the interpreter, the error message I got when install the mentioned package is:
Collecting almath

  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement almath (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for almath
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Any idea what could be wrong?
UPDATE:
using Python 2.7.15 I get the error message:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/almath/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/almath/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol'),)) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol'),)) - skipping


Requires: Python >=2.6, <3

where did you find this info?

https://pypi.org/project/almath/

I am using python 2.7.15 still doesn't work

The error message suggests doing something, have you tried that? Have you checked the project's bug tracker for issues explaining that? In any case, something that still requires Python 2 is probably abandoned and not supported. That said, please [edit] your question if you want to add info, like e.g. a link to the library you're using.

link: https://pypi.org/project/almath/

Python 3 can't find it but with 2.7 you have totally different problem - it finds it but it can't use HTTPS to download it. Maybe you have to update pip for this. OR on PyPi you can find link Download files and you can download it manually, and later you can install from local file
